# Run tmux inside EC2 user-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tmux, user-data

I'm creating an EC2 instance and setting up a Jupyter HUB server via user data. I use tmux to launch jupyter to serve notebooks content.

```
tmux new-session -s hub -d
```

Actual result:
There are no errors in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log; If I run this command:

```
tmux attach
```

I can't see any session running

Expected result:
tmux session running

Comment: Can you share the error from your logs ?  That will be helpfull to understand the problem

Comment: There are no errors in the log

Comment: sorry, I missed the "no errors" in your orginal question :-(

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su
tmux ls
```

tmux is created as root. You cannot see the sessions if you are not logged in as root.